# What does the word "screens" mean in context of a living room?

Tags: word-meaning

My landlord has just asked me to fill in an inventory and condition form, and in the section of the living room, I have come across to the words "windows and latches and screens". I have no idea what it is in my house.

Answer (score 5):

Although ***screen*** could mean several things, when it comes after ***windows*** and ***latches***, the first thing that would come to my mind would be a specific kind of "screen": [a frame with fine wire netting used in a window or doorway to keep out mosquitoes and other flying insects](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/screen) (Oxford dictionary).

A photo of an insect screen:
<sup>Source: http://www.maxdecors.com/insect_screens.php</sup>
[image: insect screen]

In any case, if you're in doubt about anything in the form, the best solution is to ask your landlord.

Answer (score -2):

Mostly likely it means curtains or blind, things attached to a window to block light coming into the room.